# Differences in Django storage systems

Tags: django

I have a Django application that uses FileSystemStorage for development and S3BotoStorage for staging and production.  Everything is working fine.  There are some small differences between these systems that I have noticed:

1. FileSystemStorage will append the MEDIA_ROOT value to any file it
   saves.  S3BotoStorage by default will not.
2. If I delete a model instance with a FileField, S3BotoStorage will
   delete the FileField's file and the directory the file is in if the
   file is the only file in that directory.  FileSystemStorage will not
   delete the empty directory.

I can work around these differences, but they add conditionals to my code.  The first of these is easiest -- I just initialize the S3BotoStorage class with `location=MEDIA_ROOT`.  Is there a way to handle the second one in a similar fashion?  Can I configure either storage class' directory deletion behavior?  Should I just override the the FileSystemStorage's delete method?

Comment: S3BotoStorage doesn't really "delete the folder" at all; in fact S3 doesn't even have folders.  Instead, S3 stores all data by key.  Because S3Boto simulates a normal file storage, it uses keys like "foo/bar/baz.txt", but it *could* just as easily use "foo;bar|baz.text" and S3 wouldn't blink.  In any case, if you have two files with keys "foo/bar" and "foo/baz", most S3 tools will show that as files "bar" and "baz" in folder "foo", but really they're two separate keys.  If you delete both keys, your tools will make it look like a folder was deleted, but really it was never there to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for this comment.  This seems obvious after your explanation -- thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for `FileSystemStorage.delete` (line 144) doesn't have any configuration that I can see:

```
def delete(self, name):
    name = self.path(name)
    # If the file exists, delete it from the filesystem.
    # Note that there is a race between os.path.exists and os.remove:
    # if os.remove fails with ENOENT, the file was removed
    # concurrently, and we can continue normally.
    if os.path.exists(name):
        try:
            os.remove(name)
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
                raise
```

So, yes, the simplest and cleanest method is probably to override its delete method to additionally check for the case of an empty directory.

Comment: I really need to get in the habit of looking at the source earlier.  Thanks!